# How to create RUNNING TOTAL in this mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
select saleid, orderno, orderdate, 
    sum(purchaseprice+purchaseshipping+paypalfee+storefee) as totalcost, 
    customerpaid as totalrevenue, 
    (customerpaid - sum(purchaseprice+purchaseshipping+paypalfee+storefee)) as profit,
    ROUND((((customerpaid - sum(purchaseprice+purchaseshipping+paypalfee+storefee)) / customerpaid) * 100.00),2) as profitmargin
from tblsales 
group by orderno having " . $having . " 
order by $sort $order limit $offset,$rows
```

This query works fine. Is there a way to add **running total profit** field to this query that performs a running sum of **profit** already calculated in the query?

Comment: You could just add the values in php

Comment: @Strawberry .. off course but my requirement is to do it in SQL

Comment: But why impose such a requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it in a subquery and use variables:

```
select t.*,
       (@cumesum := @cumesum + profit) as runningprofit
from (select saleid, orderno, orderdate, 
             sum(purchaseprice+purchaseshipping+paypalfee+storefee) as totalcost, 
             customerpaid as totalrevenue, 
             (customerpaid - sum(purchaseprice+purchaseshipping+paypalfee+storefee)) as profit,
             ROUND((((customerpaid - sum(purchaseprice+purchaseshipping+paypalfee+storefee)) / customerpaid) * 100.00),2) as profitmargin
      from tblsales 
      group by orderno
      having " . $having . " 
     ) t cross join
     (select @cumesum := 0) vars
order by $sort $order
limit $offset, $rows;
```